# fatal error: oci.h: No such file or directory

Tags: oracle, go, oracle-call-interface, instantclient

go version go1.8.1 windows/amd64
when I tried go get for oracle library

```
go get -v gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4
output: 
**gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4
# gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4
F:\CODING\src\gopkg.in\rana\ora.v4\bndBfile.go:9:10: fatal error: oci.h: No such file or directory
 #include <oci.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.**
```

and

```
**go get github.com/mattn/go-oci8
# github.com/mattn/go-oci8
F:\CODING\src\github.com\mattn\go-oci8\oci8.go:4:10: fatal error: oci.h: No such file or directory
 #include <oci.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.**
```

now when I type `pkg-config --cflags --libs oci8`
I get following result which means oci8.pc is working fine

```
-IC:instantclient_12_2sdkinclude -IC:mingw64include  -LC:instantclient_12_2sdklibmsvc -LC:mingw64lib -loci
```

please suggest whats going wrong
oci8.pc

```
prefix=/devel/target/1.0
exec_prefix=${prefix}
oralib=C:\instantclient_12_2\sdk\lib\msvc
orainclude=C:\instantclient_12_2\sdk\include
gcclib=C:\mingw64\lib
gccinclude=C:\mingw64\include
glib_genmarshal=glib-genmarshal
gobject_query=gobject-query
glib_mkenums=glib-mkenums

Name: oci8
Version: 12.2
Description: oci8 library
Libs: -L${oralib} -L${gcclib} -loci
Libs.private: 
Cflags: -I${orainclude} -I${gccinclude}
```

Comment: This looks juts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984239/go-giving-fatal-error-oci-h-no-such-file-or-directory, but with even less info.

Comment: @JimB, please suggest what else should be added to make it clear

Comment: pkg-config is finding the api8.pc file, but is that file correct? Where are your oracle headers and libraries located?

Comment: @JimB I have posted my oci8.pc in question now

Comment: If those paths are correct, and you've confirmed the go tool is actually executing `pkg-config`, are you certain that output is correct? There are no path separators in the `pkg-config` you've shown, and the example pc files for windows still seem to use forward slashes.

Comment: @JimB yes output of pkg-config is correct, do you want me to change the slashes in pc file to backward slashes

Comment: I tried changing to backward slashes, now its a different error   # gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4
gcc: warning: C:\instantclient_12_2\sdk\include: linker input file unused because linking not done
# gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4
gcc: warning: C:\instantclient_12_2\sdk\include: linker input file unused because linking not done
# gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find C:\instantclient_12_2\sdk\lib\msvc: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status